# How to get gmail contact without oauth dialogue?

Tags: c#, oauth, gmail

I am working on windows application. I get gmail contact using following code.
But in this case I must login and accept permission from browser form(GoogleLoginForm). 
I want to skip this "oauth dialog".

I have referred almost link of stack overflow and google developer. But I don't get much help regarding to this. Is there anyway to skip the permission from browser?

Please suggest.

This is my main form.

```
string SCOPE = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/";
string REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
parameters.Scope = SCOPE;

string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
Uri loginUri = new Uri(url);

GoogleLoginForm objForm = new GoogleLoginForm(loginUri);
DialogResult result= objForm.ShowDialog();
if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
     parameters.AccessCode = objForm._OAuthVerifierToken;
}

OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
RequestSettings reqSettings = new RequestSettings("myapplication", parameters) { AutoPaging = true };
ContactsRequest contReq = new ContactsRequest(reqSettings);
Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> Contacts = contReq.GetContacts();
```

I get AccessCode by following code.

```
    public GoogleLoginForm(Uri url)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _loginUri = url;
    }

    public GoogleLoginForm(Uri loginUri)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this._loginUri = loginUri;
    }
    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        string fullPath = e.Url.ToString();
        WebBrowser control = sender as WebBrowser;
        if (control != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.DocumentTitle) && control.DocumentTitle.Contains("Success code"))
        {
            _OAuthVerifierToken = control.DocumentTitle.Replace("Success code=", "");
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }

    private void GoogleLoginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Url = _loginUri;
    }
```